# What am I doing wrong (calculating volume with disks and cylindrical shells)?

Tags: calculus

I have a region bounded by $y=x^3$, $y=8$ and $x=0$. The question is to calculate the volume using the disks and also by using cylindrical shells when rotated around the x-axis.

So for the disks the radius is $(8-x^3)$, which leaves me with $\pi\int_0^2 (8-x^3)^2$. I integrate that and get $\frac{x^7}{7}-4x^4+64x$ from 0 to 2 and the answer is approximately $82\pi$.

For the shells I need to switch $y=x^3$ into terms of y, so I get $x=\sqrt[3]{y}$, which is the height of the shell. The radius of the shell is simply $y$, and so I have $2\pi\int_0^8 y(y^{\frac{1}{3}})$. That integrates into $2\pi(\frac{3y^{\frac{7}{3}}}{7})$ from 0 to 8 which gives me approximately $110\pi$.

So both of them give me different answers but I can’t figure out what’s wrong with either of them. Can somebody tell me where I messed up?

Comment: in first case you have  rotation around the x-axis and in second case you have  rotation around the y-axis.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: for the disk (washer's) method the outer radius is $8$ and inner radius is $x^3$, so the volume generated by revolving the region about the $x$-axis is $$V=\displaystyle\int_0^2\pi\big(8^2-(x^3)^2\big)dx=\pi\int_0^2(64-x^6)dx.$$